# How to read data from text file into int array of struct?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, struct, io

I've created a RentalAgency struct which contains a name, zip code, and inventory. I've also created a RentalCar class which contains the members of the inventory. I'm trying to read in the data from the text file into each respective place and I'm having trouble with it.

```
struct RentalAgency {
    char name[25]; //25 characters max
    int zipcode[5]; //5 digits in zipcode
    RentalCar inventory[5]; //5 cars
};


class RentalCar {
    int m_year;
    char m_make[256], m_model[256]; //256 characters max
    float m_price;
    bool m_available;

    public:
    RentalCar();
    RentalCar(int, char[], char[], float, bool);
    void setYear(int);
    void setMake(char[]);
    void setModel(char[]);
    void setPrice(float);
    void setAvailable(bool);
    int getYear();
    char* getMake();
    char* getModel();
    float getPrice();
    bool getAvailable();
    void print();
    float estimateCost(int);
};
```

I'm attempting to read from this text file.

```
Hertz 93619
2014 Toyota Tacoma 115.12 1
2012 Honda CRV 85.10 0
2015 Ford Fusion 90.89 0
2013 GMC Yukon 110.43 0
2009 Dodge Neon 45.25 1   

Alamo 89502
2011 Toyota Rav4 65.02 1
2012 Mazda CX5 86.75 1
2016 Subaru Outback 71.27 0
2015 Ford F150 112.83 1
2010 Toyota Corolla 50.36 1

Budget 93035
2008 Ford Fiesta 42.48 0
2009 Dodge Charger 55.36 1
2012 Chevy Volt 89.03 0
2007 Subaru Legacy 59.19 0
2010 Nissan Maxima 51.68 1
```

So far I've set up a function to read the data. I've managed to create a for loop that reads in the Rental Agency name, but I get stuck when it comes to the zip code.

```
void input(struct RentalAgency data[])
{
    char inputFile[50]; //50 characters max
    char tmp;
    std::ifstream inputStream;

    std::cout << "Enter input file name: ";
    std::cin >> inputFile;

    inputStream.open(inputFile);

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) //3 agencies 
    {   
        inputStream >> data[i].name;

        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            inputStream >> tmp;

            data[i].zipcode[j] = tmp;   
        }
    }

}
```

My output when I print the data is:

```
data[0].name = Hertz //correct
data[0].zipcode[0] = 57 //wrong
data[0].zipcode[1] = 51 //wrong
data[0].zipcode[2] = 54 //wrong
data[0].zipcode[3] = 49 //wrong
data[0].zipcode[4] = 57 //wrong
```

What I want is:

```
data[0].zipcode[0] = 9
data[0].zipcode[1] = 3
data[0].zipcode[2] = 6
data[0].zipcode[3] = 1
data[0].zipcode[4] = 9
```

Comment: does data[i].zipcode[0], data[i].zipcode[1].....data[i].zipcode[4] have now value ?

Comment: Change zipcode to a `char[6]`. Problem solved. But unless you like dealing with buffer overflows and memory corruption, and you wish to write modern C++ code, you will want to use `std::string`s instead of plain `char` arrays.

Comment: When I use data[i].zipcode[0], data[i].zipcode[1], etc.. the program reads data[i].zipcode[0] to be 93619, then data[i].zipcode[1] to be 2014. Why isn't it reading each number individually? Would I have to use atoi somewhere here?

Comment: We aren't allowed to use strings for this assignment. And it's part of the assignment for the zip code to be an integer array

Comment: I'm pretty sure you''ve misunderstood the assignment if you think you should store the zip code in an `int[5]`. Either that or the assignment is bonkers.

Comment: Well the assignment reads: The Real Agency struct will contain the member: zipcode, an int array of size 5 (Hint: You will NOT be able to use cin and cout –or any fstream objects– directly with this int array as you were doing so far with Cstrings. The reason is that reading/writing is specially handled by C++ for char array types. You will need to manage reading/writing to an int array on your own.)

Comment: "_an int array of size 5_" - Ok, and are you sure that it's only for one zip code? Such an array could easily fit 5 zip codes.

Comment: Yes i'm sure it's for one zip code because the assignment wants us to read 3 zipcodes, not 5. So 5 for each digit of the zipcode.

Comment: Ok, then the assignment is bonkers. What @SamVarshavchik suggested (`char[6]`) or one single `uint32_t` or perhaps even one single `uint16_t` (depending on whether zip codes stay below 65536 in your country or not) would be more appropriate.

Comment: `inputStream >> data[i].zipcode[j];` will do a formatted read of the whole zip code into `zipcode[0]` as you've noticed in the output. Read one `char` at a time from the stream and put it in your zipcode `int` array and then it'll work. `char tmp; inputStream >> tmp; data[i].zipcode[j] = tmp;` should do it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Okay, so I tried that, and now my program is outputting random numbers for the zip code. I've updated my original post to show what I did and what the new output is.

Comment: Oh, ok, I forgot the last part: `char tmp; inputStream >> tmp; data[i].zipcode[j] = tmp-'0';` should do it. You are reading `char`s and what you print out when printing `int`s are the [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) values of `0`-`9`. If you subtract the ASCII value for `0` you should be home.

Comment: @TedLyngmo It worked!! Thank you so much. For reading in the class members (year, make, price, availability) would I have to do it through the inventory array?

Comment: Great, I added that as an answer (that you can accept if it helped you solve the problem) too. Yes, you'll need to go through the inventory array but ideally, the parsing of each `RentalCar` should be done by a class function in `RentalCar` itself or a friend function to `RentalCar`. One usuallly adds a streaming operator for that purpose, like `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, RentalCar& rc) {...}` but I assume that since `std::string` isn't allowed, overloading `operator>>` isn't ok either?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Is this where my setYear, setModel functions come into play? We actually just learned about overloading operators, so would I use an overloading assignment operator?

Comment: No, the `set` functions you use for setting the value of individual members. Overloading `operator>>` for a class is used to read all the values for one instance of the class. A composite class, like `RentalAgency`, would then just call do something like `for(size_t idx=0; idx<5; ++idx) inputStream >> inventory[idx];` to get all `RentalCar`s read. Read about it a little and ask a new question about how to get it working if you don't get it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing the [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) values for the characters `0` - `9` in the zip code. You need to subtract the ASCII value for `0` from the character you read:

```
for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
{
    inputStream >> tmp;
    data[i].zipcode[j] = tmp - '0';
}
```

Comment: Glad it helped, but I really question why you are supposed to use an `int[5]` for storing one single zip code. I can't think of any reason to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below a full working solution, including the nonesense constraints from yout instructor.

So, we do here, what normally nobody would do.

- Usage of char arrays instead of strings (Why that? What a nonesense)
- Using plain old C-style arrays
- using magic numbers for array dimensions instead of dynamic sizes.
- using of raw pointer!
- using setters and getters for everthing, braking encapsualtion
- returning pointer to member variables

Thsi program is stongly dependent on the exact input format, which is also not good.

A more flexible approach would be better

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

std::istringstream inputFile{ R"(Hertz 93619
2014 Toyota Tacoma 115.12 1
2012 Honda CRV 85.10 0
2015 Ford Fusion 90.89 0
2013 GMC Yukon 110.43 0
2009 Dodge Neon 45.25 1

Alamo 89502
2011 Toyota Rav4 65.02 1
2012 Mazda CX5 86.75 1
2016 Subaru Outback 71.27 0
2015 Ford F150 112.83 1
2010 Toyota Corolla 50.36 1

Budget 93035
2008 Ford Fiesta 42.48 0
2009 Dodge Charger 55.36 1
2012 Chevy Volt 89.03 0
2007 Subaru Legacy 59.19 0
2010 Nissan Maxima 51.68 1
)" };

constexpr size_t MakeAndModelSize = 256;
constexpr size_t MaxInputLineSize = 1024;
constexpr size_t ZipCodeSize = 5;
constexpr size_t InventorySize = 5;
constexpr size_t NameOfAgenySize = 25;

class RentalCar {

public:
    RentalCar() {
        std::fill(m_make, m_make + MakeAndModelSize, 0);
        std::fill(m_model, m_model + MakeAndModelSize, 0);
    };
    RentalCar(int y, char* make, char* model, float price, bool available) : m_year(y), m_price(price), m_available(available)  {
        std::copy_n(make, MakeAndModelSize, m_make);
        std::copy_n(model, MakeAndModelSize, m_model);
    }

    // I am breaking the whole encapsulation 
    // We make some more noensense and define setters and getters for everything. 
    // so, we can also make all data public . . .
    void setYear(int year) { m_year = year; }
    void setMake(char* make) { std::copy_n(make, MakeAndModelSize, m_make); } 
    void setModel(char* model) { std::copy_n(model, MakeAndModelSize, m_model); }
    void setPrice(float price) { m_price = price; }
    void setAvailable(bool avail) { m_available = avail; }
    int getYear() { return m_year; };
    char* getMake() { return m_make; }; 
    char* getModel() { return m_model; } 
    float getPrice() { return m_price;  }
    bool getAvailable() { return  m_available; };
    void print() { std::cout << *this;  } // This function is not needed. We overlaoded the inserter already for that purpose
    double estimateCost(int days) { return days * m_price * (m_available ? 1.0 : 0.0);}

    // Overload inserter and extractor
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const RentalCar& rc) {
        return os << rc.m_year << ' ' << rc.m_make << ' ' << rc.m_model << ' ' << rc.m_price << ' ' << rc.m_available;
    }

    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, RentalCar& rc) {
        is >> rc.m_year >> rc.m_make >> rc.m_model >> rc.m_price >> rc.m_available;
        return is;
    }

protected:
    // The data of the car
    int m_year{};
    char m_make[MakeAndModelSize];   // Lord, forgive me, I am using a fixed size plain char array for a string
    char m_model[MakeAndModelSize];  // Lord, forgive me, I am using a fixed size plain char array for a string
    float m_price{ 0.0 };
    bool m_available{ false };
};


class RentalAgency {

public:
    // Extractor operator. Read all data from stream
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, RentalAgency& ra) {
        is >> ra.name ;
        std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<char>(is), ZipCodeSize, ra.zipcode);
        // Read all inventory data
        std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<RentalCar>(is), InventorySize, ra.inventory);
        return is;
    }

    // Inserter operator. Output Data
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const RentalAgency& ra) {

        // Show name and zip code
        os << ra.name << ' ';
        std::copy_n(ra.zipcode, ZipCodeSize, std::ostream_iterator<char>(os));
        os << '\n';
        // Print inventory data
        std::copy_n(ra.inventory, InventorySize, std::ostream_iterator<RentalCar>(os, "\n"));
        return os << '\n';
    }

protected:
    char name[NameOfAgenySize]{};
    int zipcode[ZipCodeSize]{};
    RentalCar inventory[InventorySize]{};
};

int main()
{
    RentalAgency ra1{};
    RentalAgency ra2{};
    RentalAgency ra3{};

    // Read all data
    inputFile >> ra1 >> ra2 >> ra3;

    // For verification. Write all data to std::cout
    std::cout << ra1 << ra2 << ra3;

    return 0;
}
```

Please note. I am overloading the extractor and inserter operator for the classes. With that, reading and writing is extremely easy. Please see in main.

Then I read from an istringstream. But that is the same as reading from a file. Here on SO I do not have files, so I choose this solution.